# package that works inside and outside django. Is this a good design?

Tags: python, django

I'm relative new to django and in generall to the python world. But I have experience with ruby (been working with rails for 2 years) so many concepts of python/django are not that new to me.

Anyway, I am writing an small package in python that will have a database connection and I want to use this package inside django but also in the feature outside django. So I decided take advantage of **django.db** and not worry about writing any database connection and managment stuff.

So I started writing my first models and wanted to make a first test outside of a django environment and I'm finding myself with some difficulties.

I thought about having the same configuration mechanism for my package as for any django application (I mean the settings.py file). I wrote a file (called nodjango_settings.py as a template) that only contains the DATABASES dictionary and added two custom variables to it:

```
MYAPP_DB_ID   = "myappdb"
MYAPP_DB_PREFIX = "myapp_"
DATABASES = {
  MYAPP_DB_ID: {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME':   'myappdb',
  }
}
```

The directory structure of my package is:

```
.
|-- README.txt
|-- doc
|   `-- db.txt
|-- setup.py
|-- src
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- myapp
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- exceptions.py
|       |-- models.py
|       |-- nodjango_settings.py
|       `-- nodjango_settings.pyc
`-- test
    `-- test.py
```

I was reading a little bit of djangos own code to see how to handle the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable and read the configuration file, so added the following code to `myapp/__init__py`.

```
import os

# try to look after the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable
# if not present raise an import error

# code abstract from python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py
try:
    settings_module = os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]
    if not settings_module: # If it's set but is an empty string.
        raise KeyError
except KeyError:
    raise ImportError("The DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable is not present.")


# TODO: look at python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py +93
# if you print sys.path then the project directory gets added
# in django/core/management/__init__.py with sys.path.append
from django.utils import importlib

p = importlib.import_module(settings_module)

print p.MYAPP_DB_ID
```

I wanted to test that `__init__.py` works as intended so on the root directory of my package I ran:

```
$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="src.myapp.nodjango_settings" python src/myapp/__init__.py


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/myapp/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    p = importlib.import_module(settings_module)
  File "/home/yanez/devpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py",   line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named src.myapp.nodjango_settings
```

I didn't expect that. When you create a new django application a `manage.py` file is created. And this file sets `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` the variable to the settings.py file from the perspective of the root directory of the application.

I read more code of django and realized that in `django/core/management/__init__.py` the root directory of the application is added to `sys.path`. This could also be the solution to my problem but I'm not quite sure whether it's a good idea to mess with `sys.path` or not.

I'm not quite sure whether my idea is a good one or a bad one. I'd like to know what you think about it and where/how I can improve it. Beside, if I stick to my idea, how can I read my custom varaibles in `settings.py` without having to reimport the settings module over and over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying a django project with mod_wsgi, one have to write a wsgi (python) script, that does the "sys.path" dance and sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable, then create the wsgi application object etc.

Why do I mention this ? Because, IMHO, you should not try to handle this part of the problem within "myapp", but from a distinct python script that would be the application entry point when using your app outside a django project context, and keep "myapp" as a pure library package. This launcher script would then take care of setting up the correct environement (sys.path, settings, whatever). For the record, the settings module is just a Python module, which at runtime is an ordinary python object (instance of class "module"), and there are quite a few ways (other than the default import mechanism) to create a module instance and add it to sys.modules (which is the important point here).

As a side note, having the settings in the packages doesn't make sense IMHO, it's a configuration file.

Edit : well, I knew there was something about using part of django standalone, and here it is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The part with the second python script that defines the entry point makes sense.

>>> and there are quite a few ways (other than the default import mechanism) to create a module instance and add it to sys.modules (which is the important point here).

this seems to be what I'm looking for.

>>> As a side note, having the settings in the packages doesn't make sense IMHO, it's a configuration file.

I didn't want to have it in the code. I thought it as a template that can be used once you use my package.

Comment: I'd agree with Pablo. More thoughts: With Django it's difficult just use one part (e.g. `django.db`) without getting involved in various other stuff (e.g. `settings.py`, `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, 'sys.path`). For this reason I'd recommend your python script *either* be fully independent of Django *or* fully integrated with it. For full independence this means not importing `django.db` or anything else from django and connecting to the db directly. For full integration you should make it a custom command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @scytale: I didn't mention the management commands because 1/ I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that Pablo already knows about them and 2/ they don't solve the problem of using the package outside of a Django project.

Comment: And I agree with @scytale, make it fully integrated, or not at all. It's common knowledge that one of the problems with django is that everything is so inter-related, and it's very difficult to break modules out on their own. Pablo, do you anticipate people using your library if they have to work partially within the bounds of the django framework? I can't see many libraries like that being useful IMO.